# Avoid calling toString with Objectmapper [Java 8]

Tags: java, objectmapper, httpconnection

I achieved what I was trying to accomplish, however, I am not satisfied with the unnecessary(?) string-parsing to arrive to my  goal.

Here is the simplified code:

```java
HttpURLConnection con = null;

URL url = new URL(URL);
con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// set connection parameters and make a GET-call
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//Must be a better way?
InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String currentLine;

//Build the string from the response from con
while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null)
       response.append(currentLine);

in.close();


ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(response.toString());

// I only want the child-node
String myArray = jsonNode.get("parent").get("child").toString();

// Map the response to my object
List<Car> car = objectMapper.readValue(myArray, new TypeReference<List<Car>>(){});
```

There is so much manual parsing like

1. Reading the Http connection input stream to `StringBuilder`, then calling `toString()`.
2. Retrieving the `JsonNode` and calling `toString()`

```
jsonNode.get("parent").get("child").toString()
```

to achieve my goal. I am by no means any senior- developer, and I gladly take advice and how I can remove "unnecessary" parsing.

1. The response from the API-call is in JSON already
2. Can only use **HttpURLConnection**-class for the API-call.

My Car class:

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "id",
        "color"})
public class Car {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;
    @JsonProperty("color")
    public String color;
}
```

Comment: 'There is so much parsing of the same string': no there isn't. There is one parse of the response string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is glad to see you want to improve your code.
Reading the input stream to `StringBuilder` and calling `jsonNode.toString()` is really unnecessary. In most of the case, there is always an useful API for your need.
Here is my suggestions:

1. Use [ObjectMapper#readTree(InputStream)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.InputStream)) to simplify the part for consuming the HTTP input stream.

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(con.getInputStream());
```

2. After retrieving the target `JsonNode`, create a `JsonParser` and then call

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new TreeTraversingParser(jsonNode.get("parent").get("child"));
objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser,new TypeReference<List<Car>>(){});
```